# groupby column if value is less than some value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1, 5, 100, 250, 253, 260, 700], 'qty': [3, 6, 2, 5, 64, 2, 5]})
df['time_delta'] = df.time.diff()
```

and I would like to groupby `time_delta` such that all rows where the `time_delta` is less than 10 are grouped together, `time_delta` column could be dropped, and `qty` is summed.
The expected result is

```
pd.DataFrame({'time': [1, 100, 250, 700], 'qty': [9, 2, 71, 5]})
```

Basically I am hoping there is something like a `df.groupby(time_delta_func(10)).agg({'time': 'min', 'qty': 'sum'})` func. I read up on `pd.Grouper` but it seems like the grouping based on time is very strict and interval based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with `gt` meaning greater than and `cumsum` to create a new group each time the time-delta is greater than 10

```
res = (
    df.groupby(df['time_delta'].gt(10).cumsum(), as_index=False)
      .agg({'time':'first','qty':sum})
)
print(res)
   time  qty
0     1    9
1   100    2
2   250   71
3   700    5
```